# VBA - When value enterested in dropdown, it populates with relevant information. How to select one of the values

Tags: web-scraping

I am trying to write VBA code to populate data in dropdown.

The dropdown populates with relevant data only when some contextual value is entered (else dropdown is empty).

Problem - even if the right value is entered via code, there is error because website expects -

1. Enter value
2. Dropdown displays relevant data
3. Select value
4. Click

Here is the

```
Set HTMLInput = HTMLDcoc.getElementById("hsa-symbol")
HTMLInput.Value = "CERA" 'this value gets entered in the dropdown but doesnt work 
                         'beacuse after CERA, the dropwn down displays 5 relevant 
                         'values out of that I want to select "Kajaria Ceramics Limited"
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: here is the website link - https://www.nseindia.com/report-detail/eq_security